# Word for "makes progress towards?"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

If one has a goal, then one can say that certain activities make progress towards that goal, lead to completion of the goal.

Is there a concise word for "is relevant to, makes progress towards [a goal]?"

---

Examples:

We can say something that does *not* make progress is "irrelevant," or "orthogonal."  But to say that something "is relevant to" a goal does not convey a strong sense of direct involvement and utility.

The ideal level of strength for the word is equivalent to "makes direct progress towards" if not "completes a necessary requirement of."

We want to say something like "I want to become a doctor, and going to medical school makes progress towards becoming a doctor.  Medical school is a (progressive?) activity."

Words like "advance" and "benefit" are close but seem too awkward or general:

- "I want to become a doctor, and going to medical school advances becoming a doctor.  Medical school is an (...advanciful? Kidding.) activity."
- "I want to become a dcotor, and going to medical school benefits becoming a doctor.  Medical school is a (benenficial?) activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this may go some way to *furthering your goal*.

Answer (score 1):

You could try **requisite**:

> I want to become a doctor ... Medical school is a requisite activity.

Or perhaps **developmental**

> I want to become a doctor ... To that end, medical school is a developmental activity.

Answer (score 1):

try [progressional](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/progressional)

> 2 a : the action or process of
>   progressing : advance

or [contributory](http://www.wordnik.com/words/contributory)? or

> Helping to bring about a result.

or [contributive](http://www.wordnik.com/words/contributive)

> Tending to contribute; contributing;
>   having the power or quality of giving
>   a portion of aid or influence;
>   furnishing a joint part or share.

Answer (score 1):

You could use germane, a bit stronger than relevant.